# Why does my website redirects when going to a URL of a file that doesn't exist, even if I don't have .htaccess redirecting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, host

I've been working on this for days...

When I go to the URL of a .jpg that doesn't exist, my website redirects me to a close file (1 character difference apparently). For example: 1234.jpg will redirect to 12345.jpg if 12345.jpg exists but 1234.jpg doesn't exist.

This website is not on Wordpress or other similar platforms. I took an existing code and developped on it. I have access to all the files and directories through Filezilla. I searched the .htaccess, but none of them had redirect lines. I tried to delete the .htaccess too, but same problem.

I was thinking, if we can't find the source of the issue, maybe some of you know how to code something that locally prevent any redirection from happening?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Could be that the webserver is configured to pass .jpg extensions through another handler (e.g. PHP orr something) which has code to do a redirect. Or could be that redirection is configured elsewhere, e.g. in the core Apache config (something like [this](https://www.ionos.co.uk/digitalguide/server/configuration/apache-redirects/) perhaps - although I am not an expert on this stuff by any means, just had a quick google around)

Comment: This could also be a browser caching issue, have you tested on a new browser or incognito mode? Does it behave the same? You can rule out browser issues this way.

Comment: Perhaps due to Content Negotiation? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html (Although I don't think that actually _redirects_, but just silently serves the "alternative" it found? Anyway, try and disable `MultiViews`, and see if that changes anything.)

Comment: @ADyson => It's a .conf file? I didn't see any in my website, I can try to search more.

Comment: @Ron => Right, I know the template I downloaded had something managing the cache. Not sure where to find this file. I tried with incognito mode, same problem. But maybe there is a redirect or rewrite or something like this in this file?

Comment: @CBroe => Hmmm not sure how to do this at all. Here the redirection will only happen when there is another file (and only one) with a similar name (1 character different). If several files are similar, it will offer to choose between them instead of redirecting.

Comment: `I didn't see any in my website`...are you the owner of the whole server, or on a shared hosting? Because conf files are part of the apache setup, rather than your website specifically (although configuration may be specific to your virtual host).

Comment: It would be beneficial t upload all of your configs, to the web server, what template you are using, if the template contains any PHP logic or just HTML... Right now we are only guessing...

Comment: _"Hmmm not sure how to do this at all"_ - https://serverfault.com/questions/264954/apache-multiviews-how-to-disable-it

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you have [`mod_speling`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) (one `l`) enabled in the server config.

`mod_speling` scans the directory when requesting a file that does not exist. If there is "close match" (eg. 1 character difference) then it will issue a 301 redirect to that file. (Although if there are more than 1 file that is a "close match" then a list of available files will be presented to the user!)

You can disable this behaviour in `.htaccess` with the following:

```
CheckSpelling Off
```

This option is disabled by default, so it would need to have been explicitly enabled elsewhere in the server config. (If you have access, not enabling it in the first place would be preferable.)

Note that since a 301 (permanent) redirect was issued then you will need to clear your browser (and any intermediary) caches before testing.

*Aside:* The `CheckCaseOnly` directive (part of mod_speling) is more commonly used to restrict spelling corrections to *case* only, ie. to enable case-insensitive URLs.

Comment: Awesome!

MrWhite's comment matches very accurately my situation.

I searched in all files with Notepad++ the terms 'CheckSpelling', 'CheckCase' and 'mod_speling' but couldn't find any of them.

I added the line 'CheckSpelling Off' at the end of my .htaccess and... magic. Problem solved.

It would be great if I could find where the problem comes from but at least it's fixed. Thanks a lot, and thanks to the entire community as well. I'm impressed by how fast and how valuable were the given answers!

Comment: @QuentinAwesomePowerpointsVa "It's a shared hosting." - In that case you won't have access to the server config. "I'm pretty sure it's one of the files I uploaded from a template that caused this change" - That seems unlikely since this would have needed to have been enabled in the root `.htaccess` file (which you had already edited and even deleted) in order to be able to disable this feature in the root `.htaccess` file (as I mentioned above). Or were you seeing a cached response after having removed the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @QuentinAwesomePowerpointsVa "the host wouldn't have enabled this function by default" - How can you be so sure? I totally agree that they shouldn't, but since many shared hosts appear to explicitly enable `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation - briefly mentioned in comments above) - when they shouldn't - this may not be so unlikely. (Maybe it's a "feature" in the hosting control panel?)

Comment: @QuentinAwesomePowerpointsVa Please consider "accepting" this answer (green/grey checkmark below the voting arrows) to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks, much appreciated. :)